# SQL : The influence of research speed with empty clolumns?

Tags: sql, performance, select

I'd like to know if some empty columns (with the field 'null' for example) can decrease the speed to make a query "SELECT" on a indexed column or a normal column.

Thanks,

Ba

Comment: There's a dependence on your DB type (can you add it?), and what you're trying to do with the column / index. One example (out of many) can be http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_null_idx.htm

Comment: The columns that are empties are not indexed. In this table I've a composite key of 2 columns. I've maybe 30 columns that can be empty and 2 columns that are the composite key.

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are returned to a client, then yes.  Returning the extra columns, even if they have NULLs, will take more space.

The extra columns might also have an impact on sub-queries, but a good optimizer should drop them out of the results if they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's indexed, multiple rows with the same value (null or blank for example) could make you query faster.  The difference would probably be unnoticeable though, unless your table was huge, and you went from totally random values to just a couple of different values.

Unindexed columns wouldn't make any difference.